get the new branches from original depot on my github fork
I am working on PyMoDAQ which is an opensource python projet published on github ( https://github.com/PyMoDAQ/PyMoDAQ ).
I forked this projet into my own account ( https://github.com/loicguilmard/PyMoDAQ/ ).
I have been working on the 4.2 version but since the 5.0.x_dev branch was created.
But it doesn't appear on the branches available on my fork.
I used the sync button on my fork to sync with the original depot the 5.0.x_dev. This new branch is not available on my fork but the 4.4.x did.
The few others similar questions that has been asked have at best a destroy everything/start over solution that i'd want to avoid.

I thought there would be a way to do it directly on github, but i had to add the origin repository as remote get the branches i wanted then push them back to my fork repository

This question is similar to: Git Sync to upstream: Newly created branch not showing in my fork. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The major version 5 of PyMoDAQ consists mostly in the splitting of various base features that could be worthwhile using as independant modules such as the data management: pymodaq_data, the widget and user interface bits baser on Qt: pymodaq_gui and then the utils for all this: pymodaq_utils.
Then on the remaining pymodaq original repository remains only things related to instruments, control modules, dashboard and extensions of the dashboard. It has the three other modules as dependency.
For those three new modules, they have been created firstly as forks of the pymodaq original repo then simplified to contain only what they are meant for. I didn't know at that time it would prevent someone to fork them again to work on a PR. I just happened to delete those three repo and recreated them from my local copy. They kept their history but lost the fork relation. They should therefore be "forkable" again.
Finally for your original question: the pymodaq repo itself, should still make any new branch appearing. You just have to tweak a bit your fork for this newly created branch appear: see Git Sync to upstream: Newly created branch not showing in my fork
